# detach a debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, process, detach

How do you detach from a process in visual studio? I attach to the w3wp process and clicking on "stop debugging" kills the process :( . But I need to simply detach from it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have "native, .net 4.0 and t-sql" options checked, then I can't use the "detach" button, but when I have "automatically detect" option enabled, then this button is enabled. If I attach to w3wp, then I see .net 4.0 and t-sql options enabled, if I attach to notepad.exe, then I see native code enabled. Probably trying to debug both native and .net 4.0 disables the "detach" button.

Answer (score 1):

Debug->Detach All should do the trick.

Comment: it's disabled, I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry I'm still kind of a SO newbie - didn't realize there was an updated comment. I just tried it. I booted VS attached to a running .exe and then I can detach. **HOWEVER**, maybe you are stopped on a breakpoint or have done some other operation that needs to be cleared before you are allowed to detach? In other words you have to put the attached to process back in a usable state? Just guessing.

Comment: this actually might be the case, I'll check it out! Thanks.

Comment: I can't detach it indifferently from the execution being stopped or not.

Comment: Does it work for any other process? As a test I was just booting VS2010, not loading a solution or project. Attaching to an existing process and then detaching. Not a great test but you should at least be able to do the same. If not it seems like something is wrong. Is the process running on your machine or are you remote debugging?

Answer (score -1):

Debug->Stop Debugging (Shift-F5) also should work. VS will just detach from w3wp in that case.

Comment: No, it doesn't, it kills the process, and in fact I've already written about it in my post.